# How to host thousands of small images to serve to mobile app?

Tags: image, cloud, hosting

Hi as the questions suggests. I need a service or way to serve many small images to my mobile app which will display them in a grid-like view. I am concerned mainly about speed of delivery of the images and bandwidth usage. I have looked at things like Parse and AWS as well as image sharing sites but to be honest I am not really sure.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon S3 for store your images or a similar service like Google Drive or Dropbox. Amazon S3 permits you to choose the region you want to store your images, so could be really convenience.

I guess you will need also a server to transfer these images to your clients. For this, you can use a PaaS, which uses the same region than Amazon S3 in order to have low latency between then. [Here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) you have an example which shows you how to use Amazon S3 on a Java app.